# Cannot explain a destructor call after a function call is done returning an object

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I tried running the code below and i do not understand when and why does the destructor get called at the line  `myA=foo(myOtherB)`.

My problem is that right after the foo function returns the A object, copy constructing it from 'input' and printing A copyctor, `operator=` gets called printing 'Aop' and then the destructor gets called printing A dtor.

Why is the destructor getting called at this point and not right after the return before the `operator=` call?

Another problem i have is that if i use `return A(2)` instead of `return input`
constructor A does not get called printing A ctor...

Can anyone explain?I'm sorry for the code being a bit complex.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        int x;
        A(){ cout<<"A ctor"<<endl; }
        A(const A& a){cout<<"A copyctor"<<endl; }
        virtual~A(){ cout<<"A dtor"<<endl;} 
        virtual void foo(){ cout<<"Afoo()"<<endl;}
        virtual A& operator=(const A&rhs){cout<<"Aop="<<endl; }
        A(int _x)
        {
            x=_x;
        }
};


class B:public A
{
    public:
         B(){ cout<<"B ctor"<<endl; }

         virtual~B(){ cout<<"B dtor"<<endl; }
         virtual void foo(){ cout<<"B foo()"<<endl; }
    protected:
         A mInstanceOfA; 

};

A foo(A& input)
{ input.foo(); return input; //return A(2); does not call the A constructor } 



int main()
{

    B myOtherB;
    A myA;
    myA=foo(myOtherB); 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return A();
```

This is called [**most vexing parse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).
You are not calling the constructor of `A` (not creating a new instance), but rather declaring a function which returns A (read the link for further and probably more correct explanation).

You can invoke the constructor by:

```
return A{2};
```

This is called [`Uniform initialization syntax`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) (C++ 11 and later)

---

```
A myA;
myA=foo(myOtherB);
```

In this case, you first create a new `A` object (`myA`) and then you assign the variable to the return value of the `foo` function.
This will call the assignment operator, due to the second line.
You copy the value that `foo` return to the `myA` variable.

When the already created `myA` variable is re-assigned, the old value will be destroyed, thus calling the `destructor`.

What I think you are after is the following:

```
A myA = foo(myOtherB);
```

Comment: i think i understood the constructor part but i do not actually assign anything to myA since operator= just executes a cout...so why does the destructor gets called since there s no re assignment for myA?Does = always mean re assignment no matter what u do in the operator= function?

Answer (score 0):

You return *by value*, which means that the value you return is copied into a *temporary* object, one that is later destructed.

Comment: Why does it get destructed after the call of operator= though? What does 'later' mean?

Comment: @matts The function returns by value, which means a temporary object is created by the compiler for the returned object, this temporary object is then used by the assignment operator, and once the assignment expression is over the temporary object is destructed.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried running the code below and i do not understand when and why
>   does the destructor get called at the line myA=foo(myOtherB).

Destructor will be called just before the last brace of your main function because of [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

> Why is the destructor getting called at this point and not right after
>   the return before the operator= call?

I answered this question above already, object scope the matter. Whenever your object goes out of scope, destructor will be called.

> Another problem i have is that if i use return A(2) instead of return
>   input constructor A does not get called printing A ctor...

```
A foo(A& input)
{ input.foo(); return input; //return A(2); does not call the A constructor }
```

You are returning an existing object input which your function received as reference, so system no need to create an object by calling constructor.

Comment: Destructor does not get called at the last brace of main.If i put a getchar() before the last brace of main the destructor gets called before the getchar()

Comment: @matts compiler can optimize the order of statements unless there is no specific behavioral change of your program. Even if destructor does call before or after getchar() after impact will be same.